# create the C++ equivalent of this Javascrypt file

Tags: javascript, c++

I wanted to edit a game save file (from sheltered, the game published by team17).

Unfortunately, the only thig to do it, a javascrypt file stored [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mjnpr2ac/18/) isn't working (at least the encryption part, because i was capable of decrypting the .DAT file into it's XML form...)

Could anyone help me to create a C++ equivalent?

i'm asking here because i'm a C++ beginner & i have NO knoledge regarding js.

Thanks in advance.

i'll leave a copy os the JS here just in case...

```js
var resultDataBuffer;

function encrypt(buffer) {
  var encrypters = [172, 115, 254, 242, 170, 186, 109, 171, 48, 58, 139, 167, 222, 13, 21, 33, 74];
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  var output = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    var oldValue = bytes[i];
    var encrypter = encrypters[i % encrypters.length];
    bytes[i] = oldValue ^ encrypter;
    output += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }
  
  resultDataBuffer = buffer;
  return output;
}

document.querySelector('#chooseFile').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(){
    $('#result').text(encrypt(this.result));
    var blob = new Blob([resultDataBuffer], { 'type': 'application/octet-binary' });
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    $('#downloadResult').attr('href', objectUrl);
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="chooseFile"/>
<a id="downloadResult">Download Result</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: You can't integrate C++ directly with webpages. You might, however, look at [emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html), it compiles C++ code into [WebAssembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly) which is supported by most of the popular modern browsers.

Comment: i"m not looking for adding C++ into any webpage.
i just want to know how to convert the decryption/encryption function into C++.
so i can make a standalone program (on my own) to just drag&drop save file and run it on my PC

Comment: Where are you actually stuck? Do you know how the two operators `%` (modulus) and `^` (bitwise XOR) work?

Comment: % yes
^ no

i'm stuck at the part of understanding whats happening on JS side.
so i can start making a C++ equivalent

Comment: Note: I'm not sure whether this encrypted output actually makes it to that Blob.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost a one-to-one translation:

```
static uint8_t key[] = { 172, 115, 254, 242, 170, 186, 109, 171, 48, 58, 139, 167, 222, 13, 21, 33, 74 };
std::vector<uint8_t> encrypt(std::vector<uint8_t> bytes) {
  std::vector<uint8_t> output;
  int i = 0;
  for (auto b : bytes) {
    auto encrypter = key[i++ % sizeof key];
    output.push_back(b ^ encrypter);
  }
  return output;
}
```

Also note that this is an XOR cipher, so the same function is used for decryption.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.
At the end I got help from a developer on the PS2 community:

```cpp
std::string encrypt(unsigned char *buf,int size)
{
  unsigned char encrypters[17] = {172, 115, 254, 242, 170, 186, 109, 171, 48, 58, 139, 167, 222, 13, 21, 33, 74};
  std::string output;
  for( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
      unsigned char oldValue = buf[i];
      unsigned char encrypter = encrypters[i % 17];
      buf[i] = oldValue ^ encrypter;
      output += (char)buf[i];
   }
  return output;
}
```